# Open NFC Simulator hangs when pulling NFC Device #2

Tags: android, android-emulator, nfc, open-nfc

I'm currently experimenting NFC with android emulator and Open NFC. I have setup OpenNFC as described here [P2P in Android using Open NFC virtual device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405601/p2p-in-android-using-open-nfc-virtual-device), running 2 emulator instances then clicking "NFC Device #2" to simulate device touching. It works as expected, the tag is sent to the other device. The problem is when I double click "NFC Device #2" to simulate pulling, the NFC simulator always hangs. Anyone else having this problem?